# What does a program (the assembly) that uses a GPU even look like?

Tags: assembly, gpu

From [this answer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/7814), it seems that GPU manufacturers just provide a driver for particular GPU APIs, and that there's no such thing as GPU assembly or at the very least, there will never be a GPU assembly programming manual published like the [AMD64 programmer's manual](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24592.pdf)

However, as I understand, all processes run go through the CPU, and can be disassembled.

My question is: What would the assembly of a program using the GPU look like? My hypothesis is that it would use system calls to manipulate a device file representing the GPU. Is this hypothesis correct?

Comment: **Why do you ask?** Is it curiosity, or much more.

Comment: Curiosity. I am in a technology oriented profession, but this is not to do with work.

Comment: There's been publicly released documentation on the instruction set some GPUs use. GPUs are basically CPUs with a very specific purpose, graphics rendering. They're not really like floating point coprocessors. which were extensions of the main CPU that used to sit an a separate chip next to it.  A GPU is essentially a second computer inside your PC, often with its own RAM. A program running on a CPU uses a GPU by downloading graphics data, shader programs to the GPU and sending drawing and other commands. Generally this is done through an API like DirectX or OpenGL.

Comment: Are you asking about an x86-64 program that *uses* the GPU (via drivers / system calls)?  That's just x86-64 machine code, same as if it was making different system calls.  (Or more usually library function calls to driver libraries).

Comment: What actually runs *on* the GPU hardware is machine code produced by the GPU drivers (running on the CPU).  For some GPUs, there are open-source implementations of compilers from OpenCL or SPIR to actual GPU hardware machine code (or asm).

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes. That's all I'm asking. But what would this x86-64 machine code look like? What system calls/instructions would be used?

Comment: Use `strace` on a demo program like `glxgears` and see what system calls it makes!  Or single-step it with a debugger.  x86-64 machine code is x86-64 machine code; see https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html for a list of instructions.  There aren't special instructions to use the GPU; it's effectively a PCIe device with memory-mapped MMIO registers that the CPU can access with load/store instructions.  (The code inside the kernel driver will do that to program the GPU).

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok. In the long strace of `glxgears`, I see the following:

```open("/dev/nvidiactl", O_RDWR)          = 4
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
ioctl(4, _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE, 0x46, 0xd2, 0x48), 0x7ffe9d4a33c0) = 0
ioctl(4, _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE, 0x46, 0xca, 0x04), 0x7f8765bf4480) = 0
ioctl(4, _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE, 0x46, 0xc8, 0xa00), 0x7f8765bf44a0) = 0
ioctl(4, _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE, 0x46, 0x2b, 0x20), 0x7ffe9d4a3410) = 0
ioctl(4, _IOC(_IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE, 0x46, 0x2a, 0x20), 0x7ffe9d4a33f0) = 0```
I assume this would be it?

Comment: @extremeaxe5: a much simpler approach is to study the code of some OpenCL free software library, as recommended in my answer. To do that, budget several months of work

Comment: @extremeaxe5: yup, exactly.  Put some values in some registers, and run a `syscall` instruction.  That invokes some kernel code, which again is just ordinary x86-64 machine code that does loads and stores to device registers.  At some point some software is going to compile your OpenCL code to actual GPU machine code and upload that program to the GPU, but that's done in libraries.  If you want to see the GPU machine code, reverse-engineered open-source drivers might be your best bet.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouveau_(software)

Comment: look at the raspberry pi gpu instruction set for example, its just another processor in some repects, just like a dsp is just another processor, but it may have features that help it do its job (more fpu restisters, larger multiply blocks, better bit manipulation, whatever).

Comment: if you are talking about host code then its nothing special, what does it need to do?  send some commands and data to a peripheral just like a network card driver or a usb driver or other.  no magic. operating system and window manager or graphics library specific. nothing special, no magic, trivial to examine for yourself

Comment: the assembly/machine code for the host is even more uninteresting as it is just what the compiler produced for that library just like it produces for all compiled, code, takes the high level code, compiles it, that gets assembled, done.

Answer (score 5):

> ### What does code that uses a GPU even look like?

Read much more about [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) (or, for Nvidia hardware only, about [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)). Be also aware of [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC) ! See also [OpenCL related resources](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/resources), and read some OpenCL book. Read some [OpenCL tutorial](https://anteru.net/blog/2012/getting-started-with-opencl-part-1/).

In practice, you'll never see the "assembler code" of your [GPGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units). But you'll code using OpenCL (it is *very* low-level, and tuning your code to your *particular* hardware is difficult and error-prone).

AFAIK, AMD tend to publish the "machine code specification" (e.g. the [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture)) of most of its GPUs. Nvidia is much more secretive. Notice that [SPIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Portable_Intermediate_Representation) is "assembly-like" (actually [LLVM](https://llvm.org/) [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) based), but still not exactly an assembler.

> My question is: What would the assembly of a program using the GPU look like? My hypothesis is that it would use system calls to manipulate a device file representing the GPU. Is this hypothesis correct?

The system calls (very hardware specific) are transmitting the SPIR or equivalent bytecode (and often GPGPU-specific machine code) from CPU (and virtual memory) to GPU, and also the *data* from GPGPU to CPU (& memory) and back. Details are boringly complex, and generally proprietary to hardware manufacturers.  You prefer to use the OpenCL (or the CUDA) API and dialect. *Your hypothesis is wrong, or at least oversimplified* to the point of being meaningless.

Look also into [osdev.org](https://osdev.org/) wiki.

Actually, **several [open-source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) numerical libraries** (such as [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow), [OpenCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV), [BLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms), ...) **have OpenCL backends**. So take several months to **study their source code.**

Understanding all the details will give you a PhD. [Albert Cohen](https://who.rocq.inria.fr/Albert.Cohen/) (and many other experts) might be your advisor.

Read also more about [AMDGPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMDGPU) and their [GCN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next). For example, look into [AMD Vega](https://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2017/08/Vega_Shader_ISA_28July2017.pdf) specification.

> However, as I understand, all processes run go through the CPU, and can be disassembled.

**This is a very naive claim**, and I believe it is **wrong** (at least for the programs I like writing, they all somehow *generate* code at runtime). And in practice, you won't understand the disassembled code (that is why [decompilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler) is so difficult). For example of programs generating machine code, look (on Linux) into [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) (its [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) is emitting machine code at every user interaction), or into any [meta-program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), or most programs using [JIT-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques (in practice, most Java JVMs are doing JIT translation). My [`manydl.c`](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) Linux program is generating C code at runtime, compiling that into a [shared library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries) i.e. a [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) which can be [dynamically linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker), then [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)-ing that plugin (and can repeat all that many hundred thousands of time). For an example of library helpful to generate machine code, see [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/).

You should also read more about OSes in general. I strongly recommend [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable).

Comment: OK. I took at look at the page on OpenCL. It says "OpenCL views a computing system as consisting of a number of compute devices, which might be central processing units (CPUs) or "accelerators" such as graphics processing units (GPUs), attached to a host processor (a CPU)"

Right. So the program must ultimately be run on a host processor. What would the assembly of this program look like?

Comment: BTW, edited my post to be more clear. I am not asking about GPU assembly, but rather the CPU assembly of a program that uses a GPU. For example, suppose program `matmul` uses a gpu. Where, in the disassembly of `matmul`, is the GPU used?

Comment: But you really stay confused, and I don't understand why OpenCL is not enough for you

Comment: I think I would be less confused if you could answer my above comment:  For example, suppose program `matmul` uses a gpu (`matmul` is a normal ELF file you'd run using `./matmul` on Linux). Where, in the disassembly of `matmul`, is the GPU used?

Comment: Get that program as a free software in source form

Comment: You know, I would do this, and then literally comb the disassembly, but there are two problems. First, I don't know of any such program. The above was hypothetical. Second, I don't know what to look for.

Comment: My answer mentions *several* open-source libraries claiming to use OpenCL

Comment: Ok, but I have no idea where to look in the disassembly, or even what files to look for. Everything is hidden under some layers of APIs.

Comment: And why don't you want to use these layers of APIs? That reason should be written in your question!

Comment: @extremeaxe5, understand as you peel away layers of the onion, you ultimately get to the proprietary level where you are not going to be able to peel that layer away. That is intentional and is what Basile explained in his answer. You can always dump the registers of the CPU, but without the proprietary API code/reference, it will be meaningless. (notwithstanding the multi-core, multi-threaded scheduling issues) The packages like OpenCL, get you as close as you are going to get.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: "You can always dump the registers of the GPGPU" is a *very optimistic* claim.

Comment: No, no... not the GPGPU, the normal old CPU in whatever interplay it is happening to do with the GPGPU. Which is why it would be essentially meaningless. I agree with you and did not intend to indicate you are always able to dump the GPGPU, especially in the case of the proprietary hardware, I would be surprised if you could. That is the layer of the onion you can't get to.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a Nvidia GPU, then you can you can view the [PTX](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/) assembly code. PTX is only pseudo-assembly, sort of in between OpenCL and the binary code that actually runs on the GPU.
This is how you get to it from OpenCL:

```c
Context context(device);
queue = CommandQueue(context, device); // queue to push commands for the device
Program::Sources source;
string kernel_code = opencl_code_settings(N,M)+opencl_code();
source.push_back({ kernel_code.c_str(), kernel_code.length() });
Program program(context, source);
if(program.build("-cl-fast-relaxed-math")) return false; // compile OpenCL code, return false if there is an error
const string ptx_code = program.getInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES>()[0]; // generate assembly (ptx) for OpenCL code
```

The string `ptx_code` is what you are looking for. Here is a small example kernel:

```c
kernel void benchmark_1(global float* data) {
    const uint n = get_global_id(0);
    #pragma unroll
    for(uint i=0; i<def_M; i++) data[i*def_N+n] = 0.0f;
}
```

This is what the PTX code for this kernel looks like:

```
//
// Generated by NVIDIA NVVM Compiler
//
// Compiler Build ID: UNKNOWN
// Driver 
// Based on LLVM 3.4svn
//

.version 6.2
.target sm_61, texmode_independent
.address_size 64

    // .globl   benchmark_1

.entry benchmark_1(
    .param .u64 .ptr .global .align 4 benchmark_1_param_0
)
{
    .reg .b32   %r<23>;
    .reg .b64   %rd<34>;


    ld.param.u64    %rd1, [benchmark_1_param_0];
    mov.b32 %r1, %envreg3;
    mov.u32     %r2, %ntid.x;
    mov.u32     %r3, %ctaid.x;
    mad.lo.s32  %r4, %r3, %r2, %r1;
    mov.u32     %r5, %tid.x;
    add.s32     %r6, %r4, %r5;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd2, %r6, 4;
    add.s64     %rd3, %rd1, %rd2;
    mov.u32     %r7, 0;
    st.global.u32   [%rd3], %r7;
    add.s32     %r8, %r6, 15728640;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd4, %r8, 4;
    add.s64     %rd5, %rd1, %rd4;
    st.global.u32   [%rd5], %r7;
    add.s32     %r9, %r6, 31457280;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd6, %r9, 4;
    add.s64     %rd7, %rd1, %rd6;
    st.global.u32   [%rd7], %r7;
    add.s32     %r10, %r6, 47185920;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd8, %r10, 4;
    add.s64     %rd9, %rd1, %rd8;
    st.global.u32   [%rd9], %r7;
    add.s32     %r11, %r6, 62914560;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd10, %r11, 4;
    add.s64     %rd11, %rd1, %rd10;
    st.global.u32   [%rd11], %r7;
    add.s32     %r12, %r6, 78643200;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd12, %r12, 4;
    add.s64     %rd13, %rd1, %rd12;
    st.global.u32   [%rd13], %r7;
    add.s32     %r13, %r6, 94371840;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd14, %r13, 4;
    add.s64     %rd15, %rd1, %rd14;
    st.global.u32   [%rd15], %r7;
    add.s32     %r14, %r6, 110100480;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd16, %r14, 4;
    add.s64     %rd17, %rd1, %rd16;
    st.global.u32   [%rd17], %r7;
    add.s32     %r15, %r6, 125829120;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd18, %r15, 4;
    add.s64     %rd19, %rd1, %rd18;
    st.global.u32   [%rd19], %r7;
    add.s32     %r16, %r6, 141557760;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd20, %r16, 4;
    add.s64     %rd21, %rd1, %rd20;
    st.global.u32   [%rd21], %r7;
    add.s32     %r17, %r6, 157286400;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd22, %r17, 4;
    add.s64     %rd23, %rd1, %rd22;
    st.global.u32   [%rd23], %r7;
    add.s32     %r18, %r6, 173015040;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd24, %r18, 4;
    add.s64     %rd25, %rd1, %rd24;
    st.global.u32   [%rd25], %r7;
    add.s32     %r19, %r6, 188743680;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd26, %r19, 4;
    add.s64     %rd27, %rd1, %rd26;
    st.global.u32   [%rd27], %r7;
    add.s32     %r20, %r6, 204472320;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd28, %r20, 4;
    add.s64     %rd29, %rd1, %rd28;
    st.global.u32   [%rd29], %r7;
    add.s32     %r21, %r6, 220200960;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd30, %r21, 4;
    add.s64     %rd31, %rd1, %rd30;
    st.global.u32   [%rd31], %r7;
    add.s32     %r22, %r6, 235929600;
    mul.wide.u32    %rd32, %r22, 4;
    add.s64     %rd33, %rd1, %rd32;
    st.global.u32   [%rd33], %r7;
    ret;
}
```

From the PTX code you can for example [count the FLOPs and memory transfers](https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/PTXprofiler) in order to examine how efficient the code runs via the roofline model.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering this too. I found this answer with good details

> [...interaction with kernel for rendering as well as making use of GPU for preparing a scene before rendering a frame happen via ioctls to a DRM device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63785241/16645393)

---

Not sure, but if you were interested in lower level details like I was:

- [Ycombinator answer](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=30860259#:%7E:text=From%20the%20perspective%20of%20software%20running%20on%20the%20CPU%2C%20these%20days%2C%20that%20communication%20is%20typically%20in%20the%20form%20of%20memory%2Dmapped%20IO.%20The%20GPU%20has%20registers%20and%20memory%20mapped%20into%20the%20CPU%20address%20space%20using%20PCIE.)
- [A couple years old, but very detailed description of what's going on under the hood of graphics APIs like openGL](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-1/#:%7E:text=The%20KMD%20then%20writes%20a%20call%20to%20command%20buffer%20into%20the%20main%20command%20buffer%2C%20and%20depending%20on%20whether%20the%20GPU%20command%20processor%20can%20read%20from%20main%20memory%20or%20not%2C%20it%20may%20also%20need%20to%20DMA%20it%20to%20video%20memory%20first)

From what I read, it seems like protocols for communicating to GPUs have probably changed a lot, but at a high level I think it's something like below (I'm sorry it's hand wave-y and not that precise)

1. the cpu takes shader code, compiles it to instructions that a GPU core can understand
2. the CPU loads these instructions into its memory mapped address space that is connected to the gpu (I'm guessing this can be executed via `ioctl` system calls in user-space).
3. The CPU maybe has a specific memory mapped address it can write to to tell the graphics card it's done
4. The graphics card then loads this shader program into its memory for the GPUs to execute
5. and so on...

---

Ben Eater's videos on youtube were awesome, super helpful for understanding what happens on a hardware level when you, say, wanna display a pixel on your screen.  He has a series where he interfaces a microcontroller directly to an lcd screen via VGA and writes assembly code to display an image on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

**To put it simplest:**

- Nvidia GPU -> **PTX** *(Parallel Thread Execution)*
- AMD GPU    -> **GCN** *(Graphics Core Next)* / **ROCm** *(Radeon Open Compute)*

---

**To add onto the "microarchitecture" information:**

- CUDA uses NVCC as its compiler

With NVCC you can use the *--ptx* flag to generate ptx from your CUDA source files.

With NVCC you can also specify an architecture using *-arch=typehere*
[image]

---

[More information](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/) from Nvidia's site.

Comment: PTX is a virtual / intermediate assembly language, like LLVM-IR.  It has to get compiled by the NVidia drivers for the specific architecture of the GPU, to make the machine code that will get executed by the actual hardware.