# Does libdrm talk to kernel DRM/graphics card via ioctl()?

Tags: c, graphics, linux-kernel, ioctl, drm

This can be a silly question as I do not know much about this topic at all... It seems that user applications can talk directly to GPU to render an image, for example using OpenGL, through mesa and libdrm, where the libdrm is a wrapper around various ioctl() calls, as illustrated in [this graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager#/media/File:Linux_AMD_graphics_stack.svg). Does it mean that for every new frame of a 3D game, the game application needs to call the ioctl() once (or maybe even twice if KMS needs to be reached)? That sounds like a lot of user-kernel space barrier crossing (thinking about a 120 fps game).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

libdrm is an user space wrapper to perform fine grained access of the underlying KMS driver features like modesetting, checking if plane being used is an overlay plane or primary plane etc. libdrm implementations are generally different for various CPU/GPU/OS combinations, as the h/w driver running in kernel tend to support different set of functionalities apart from the standard ones. The standard way of working with libdrm is to open a drm device available in `/dev/` node and perform libdrm function calls using the fd returned from `open()`.

More often than not, the display compositor software for a particular OS like X11, wayland, hardware-composer will need to be in control of the drm device, which means non privileged applications have no way of being DRM master. Most of the libdrm mode setting functionalities do not work if the application trying to use them are not the DRM master. Recommended practice instead of using libdrm directly, is to use a standard graphics library like openGL or VULKAN to prepare and render frames in your application.

The number of ioctls required to interact with the kernel DRM module is most likely not the biggest bottleneck you will face when trying to render high FPS applications. The preferred way to run high fps applications while cooperating with the display compositor of the target system is to have

- a double or triple buffered setup for rendering, where the next buffer to be rendered is ready to be rendered before the current frame has finished rendered.
- Take advantage of h/w acceleration wherever possible, e.g for performing scaling/resizing/image format conversions/color space conversions.
- Pre compute and reuse shader elements
- Try to reuse texture elements as much as possible instead of computing a lot of textures for every frame being rendered.
- Use vector/SIMD/SSEv2,3,4/AVX/neon instructions wherever possible to take advantage of modern CPU pipelines

Comment: Thanks for answering. So in the end, are libdrm function calls implemented using ioctl()? What I am curious about is this - the user eventually needs to reach the functionalities inside the kernel DRM, or whatever kernel module functions statically/dynamically loaded, and ioctl() seems to be the only way in this case, is that correct? Another questions regarding your comments, when user have a double buffer buffer and renders into those buffers either w/ or w/o h/w acceleration, those rendering calls eventually also needs to happen through an ioctl() call, is that correct?

Comment: I guess my question is this - to call kernel/module functions from userspace, or to render something into RAM/VRAM, the user has to cross the user/kernel barrier, and he can only do that via standard syscalls, or ioctl calls (which is sort of a catch-all interface), and there is no other ways. Is that right?

Comment: @QnA That is right, interaction with kernel for rendering as well as making use of GPU for preparing a scene before rendering a frame happen via ioctls to a DRM device. The DRM subsystem takes care of both GPU interactions from the OS, as well as display interaction. Applications which make use of either GPU/display subsystems use ioctls directly or indirectly to talk to the kernel

Comment: That helps a lot, thanks again. I understand your answer is broader/deeper than my initial question, but bear with me for one more second... So the ioctl call has to happen (directly or indirectly) at least once (and maybe more) per frame, such as some prep work, followed by rendering, following by 'I am done, go display it'? And what you said is that this 120+ ioctl calls per second for a 120 fps game is not that expensive compared to other costs, is that correct?

Comment: @QnA Yes, there must be at least 1 ioctl call that happens per frame, especially for "I am done, go display it". 120+ ioctls per second should not be an expensive command, or should not be a bottleneck for an application compared to other areas I mentioned in the answer

Comment: @QnA Glad to be of help!